# In Bot Framework How to return the selected value from adaptive card[images and Choices] using node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am trying to create a bot using Bot Framework and node js , I am trying to implement Select your Mode of Transport feature through adaptive card, I am able to display the card along with images and choices , but i am not able to return the value and move to next step, Please find the output of adaptive card and code below and help me with the solution

TransportMode.json

```
    {
        "type": "ImageSet",
        "imageSize": "medium",
        "images": [
            {
                "type": "Image",
                "url":  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/ANA_777-300_Taking_off_from_JFK.jpg/300px-ANA_777-300_Taking_off_from_JFK.jpg"
            },
            {
                "type": "Image",
                "url": "https://images8.alphacoders.com/436/436769.jpg"
            },
            {
                "type": "Image",
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/LT_471_%28LTZ_1471%29_Arriva_London_New_Routemaster_%2819522859218%29.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Airplane"
        },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Railway"
        
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Bus"
    }
  ]
```

}

dialog.js file

```
async transportStep(step) {
    step.values.ticketNumber = step.result;
    console.log(step.values.ticketNumber)
    const cardPrompt = MessageFactory.text('');
    const TransportMode  = require('../bots/resources/TransportMode.json');
     await step.context.sendActivity({
        attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(TransportMode)]
     });
    
   // cardPrompt.attachments = [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(TransportMode)];
    return await step.prompt(NAME_PROMPT, 'Tell us your name');
    
}
```

[Adaptive card output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcbbQ.png)

Comment: Can you help clarify what you expect to happen in this step? It looks like you are importing and displaying the card, but then you are prompting the customer for their name? I think I can help but I need to understand when you are expecting a mode of transport prompt and when you are expecting a name prompt.

Comment: I wanted to fetch the selected input from Adaptive card; Anyways i found the solution, Thanks for your time! By just assigning the value to data in json i was able to fetch.

Comment: Great, I would encourage you to post your solution as an answer here so that others who have the same question can find it. You can accept it at the answer after some delay.